# How to design a class for unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have a Java class like the following:

```
public class MyClass {

    /** Database Connection. */
    private dbCon;

    public MyClass() {
        dbCon = ...
    }

    public void doSomethingWith(MyData data) {
        data = convertData(data);
        dbCon.storeData(data);
    }

    private MyData convertData(MyData data) {
        // Some complex logic...
        return data;
    }
}
```

since the true logic of this class lies in the `convertData()` method, I want to write a Unit Test for this method.
So I read this post

[How do I test a private function or a class that has private methods, fields or inner classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/how-do-i-test-a-private-function-or-a-class-that-has-private-methods-fields-or)

where a lot of people say that the need to test a private method is a design smell. How can it be done better?

I see 2 approaches:

1. Extract the `convertData()` method into some utility class with a public api. But I think this would be also bad practice since such utility classes will violate the single responsibilty principle, unless I create a lot of utility classes with maybe only one or two methods.
2. Write a second constructor that allows injection of the `dbCon`, which allows me to inject a mocked version of the database connection and run my test against the public `doSomething()` method. This would be my preferred approach, but there are also discussions about how the need of mocking is also a code smell.

Are there any best practices regarding this problem?

Comment: You need to inject `dbCon` and test `doSomethingWith`. "the need of mocking is also a code smell." - how, where, who?

Comment: If `convertData` doesn't depend on fields in `MyClass` (i.e. is a pure function), there's no harm in making it `public static` IMHO. Java somewhat forces you into this "everything must be an object" mindset and away from the functional principles that lend themselves _so_ well to unit testing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Extract the convertData() method into some utility class with a public api. But I think this would be also bad practice since such utility classes will violate the single responsibility principle, unless I create a lot of utility classes with maybe only one or two methods.

You interpretation of this is wrong. That is exactly what the SRP and SoC *(Separation of Concerns)* suggests

```
public interface MyDataConverter {
    MyData convertData(MyData data);
}

public class MyDataConverterImplementation implements MyDataConverter {
    public MyData convertData(MyData data) {
        // Some complex logic...
        return data;
    }
}
```

`convertData` implementation can be now tested in isolation and independent of `MyClass`

> Write a second constructor that allows injection of the dbCon, which allows me to inject a mocked version of the database connection and run my test against the public doSomething() method. This would be my preferred approach, but there are also discussions about how the need of mocking is also a code smell.

Wrong again. Research Explicit Dependency Principle.

```
public class MyClass {
    private DbConnection dbCon;
    private MyDataConverter converter;

    public MyClass(DbConnection dbCon, MyDataConverter converter) {
        this.dbCon = dbCon;
        this.converter = converter;
    }

    public void doSomethingWith(MyData data) {
        data = converter.convertData(data);
        dbCon.storeData(data);
    }
}
```

`MyClass` is now more honest about what it needs to perform its desired function.

It can also be unit tested in isolation with the injection of mocked dependencies.